# Notepad++ Delete everything before third semi colon

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge list of lines in this format:

```
9;"1258923865";"94.193.26.109";"name@email.com"
```

I am trying to delete everything except the email.

I know there is some regular expression that will do this.

Answer (score 5):

This regular expresion should match your request.

```
^.+;
```

Since the **+** quantitier is greedy it will match the whole line. Then it will backtrack just enough to allow the last semicolon to match. You end up leaving the double quotes and the email inside it intact.

Comment: How to change this regex to remove only the part until the first semicolon?

Comment: You just need to use `^.+?;`