# How to remove text before | character in notepad++

Tags: text, notepad++

I have a document like this, so i wan't to remove text before | character on any line. Work in notepad++. So what i can do?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notepad++ Delete everything before third semi colon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385892/notepad-delete-everything-before-third-semi-colon)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Please use regex to remove anything before |

example

```
dsfdf | fdfsfsf
dsdss|gfghhghg
dsdsds |dfdsfsds
```

Use find and replace in notepad++

find: `.+(\|)`
replace: `\1`

output

```
| fdfsfsf
|gfghhghg
|dfdsfsds
```

Comment: Just FYI have matches newline unticked

Comment: Do you want to delete everything before the | and including the | character. You can try find: (.+\|)  and leave replace empty.

Comment: This doesn't work, it just removes the last line of the file.

Answer (score 5):

To replace anything that starts with "**text**" until the **last character**:

```
text.+(.*)$
```

**Example**

```
text             hsjh sdjh sd          jhsjhsdjhsdj hsd
                                                      ^
                                                      last character
```

---

To replace anything that starts with "**text**" until "**123**"

```
text.+(\ 123)
```

**Example**

```
text fuhfh283nfnd03no3 d90d3nd 3d 123 udauhdah au dauh ej2e
^                                   ^
From here                     To here
```